# What is the core of TeX as a programming language?

Tags: tex-core, programming

Tex (and LaTeX) mix programming elements with typesetting ones. It's often confusing to a beginner to tell them apart. Could anyone show me a list of the very core commands of TeX (and perhaps LaTeX) as a programming language?

Comment: See The TeXbook by D.E. Knuth for the former, and LaTeX User Guide a Reference Manual, by L. Lamport for the latter.

Comment: For TeX itself, the usual suggestion would be _The TeXbook_ or _TeX by Topic_. For LaTeX2e it's well-known that bits of TeX mix with bits of documented programming code and other 'stuff'. Perhaps you could specify a little more more what your focus is?

Comment: I suppose one may consider the so-called *primitive TeX commands* -- macros such as `\relax`, `\expandafter`, `\vcenter`, etc -- to be the "core" of TeX as a *language*. The TeX primitives are listed in the TeXbook as well as in other documents. However, the primitives alone are not suitable for ordinary typesetting needs. Knuth defined a set of macros generally known as the "Plain TeX" *format*; these are also listed in the TeXbook. Additional primitives are defined in eTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX. LaTeX as a format implements many (most?) Plain-TeX macros -- and adds many more.

Comment: To the extent that *TeX by Topic* organizes commands thematically, I think it is probably the best resource to answer your question. But the distinction isn't always so clearcut. For example, one might categorize the various box commands as typesetting, but would  conditionals involving boxes be programming or typesetting.  Similar questions will arise in other types of commands too.

Comment: TeX is a programming language for typesetting. There is no distinction between programming elements and typesetting ones, since the purpose of the programming is typesetting.

Comment: Thank you all, guys. I was thinking of defining variables, conditionals, loops, and some data structures, like arrays and so on.

Comment: It is best not to do any programming in TeX IMO (and systems like LuaTeX are making it easier to avoid TeX macro “programming”). As a typesetting system TeX is matchless, but as a programming system… well it is perhaps matchless there too, but in a bad way. :-)